# Mercurial on IIS7 connection timeout

Tags: iis, mercurial

I configured Mercurial on IIS 7 and I am able tu push and pull without problems some test files.
But if I try to push a bigger repository I get for the `hg push` command line this error:

```
abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

From Tortoise HG I get some more detail:

```
lopen error [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```

It seemed to me to be some kind of connection timeout for the CGI, but I extended the cgi timeout properties in IIS7 configuration. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial client error 255 and HTTP error 404 when attempting to push large files to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068627/mercurial-client-error-255-and-http-error-404-when-attempting-to-push-large-files)

Comment: marslogic has your answer down below on another question that's pretty much identical.  It's a shame his answer never got picked there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this one, where I provided a solution to the same problem: [Client error when attempting to push large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068627/mercurial-client-error-255-and-http-error-404-when-attempting-to-push-large-files/3079399#3079399).